# Названия атрибутов

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Как узнать имена всех атрибутов элемента?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
var arr = $("#someID")[0].attributes;
//var arr = document.getElementById("someID").attributes;
for(var i in arr) alert(arr[i].nodeName)
```

`arr[i].nodeValue` - их значения

**UPD:**

Лучше так. Arr - это, оказывается, объект.

```
while(arr[i].nodeName){
    alert(arr[i].nodeName)
    i++;
}
```